# Error 403.14 when installing WebService on IIS7

Tags: web-services, iis, iis-7

I try to install my WebService on IIS7, but I get this error:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory

on IIS5 I know how to do it, can I get any direction ?

Comment: There is no real difference between running a webservice on IIS5 and IIS7.  Are you getting an error?  Configuration problems?  More information please.

Comment: i go this error:
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the correct URL, such as http://localhost/somepath/someservice.asmx (or .svc) If you don't specify the service part, of course you get 403.14.